# Problem with notification bar in fullscreen app

Tags: android, fullscreen

I run an app in fullscreen mode where fullscreen is defined as a theme in xml for the entire app.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Generally it works ok, but there are some issues in some cases:

1. when I open the search dialog via search button  -> [Screenshot](http://www.mathiaslin.com/dl/statusbar.png)
2. when I open spinner widgets that are very long and fill the screen (so that the list is usually scrollable)  -> [Screenshot](http://www.mathiaslin.com/dl/statusbar2.png)

**The problem is that when I open the search dialog or spinner widget, the system notification bar occurs for a few millisecs and then scrolls off the screen again. 
Please see the screenshots linked above.**

I'm currently on 2.2 with NexusOne, but same thing happened on 2.1update1 (esp. case 2) as well before.

Comment: The only way to avoid it is to turn off all animations under device settings / display / animation.
Seems like a bug in the Android WindowManager to me, or does anybody have a solution for it?

Comment: Ok, I see it's a known bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674&q=fullscreen&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: For closure, you should answer your own question below by referring to the known bug and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Correct url of bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to avoid it is to turn off all animations under device settings / display / animation.

I just see it's a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674

Comment: still glitches, but without the notification bar. not really a complete solution (also would it be possible to disable the animation just for the search?)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code after you create the dialog, but before setContentView:

Dialog dialog = new .....

dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

dialog.setContentView....

Comment: that does not work because you don't have a handle on the search box

Comment: can you? find the window used for the search?

Comment: I don't see why you would not be able to get a pointer to it?

Comment: because the search dialog is create when i press the search button without ever entering my code, afaik.

Comment: youll have to provide the code of making the search button active